# Spring boot HTTP get request return a String and a file

Tags: java, spring-boot, httpresponse, http-get

I have a Sprint boot application using an angular 4 front page. From my front page I send a HTTP get request with an SQL query and some other parameters.

Now I want the reponse to be a `String`+`zip file` .

I know that I can send back a file like that :

```
return ResponseEntity.ok()
    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"")
    .body(file);
```

but I have no idea how to combine a file and a String in the `ReponseEntity`.

Here is my code so far (server side) :

Controller :

```
@GetMapping("/sql")
public ResponseEntity<String> handleSqlRequest(
    @RequestParam("sql") String sql, 
    @RequestParam("source") String source, 
    @RequestParam("genFile") Boolean genFile
) { 
    SqlToolResponse sqlToolResponse;
    if(genFile) {
        //Create a ZIP file and execute sql
        sqlToolResponse = this.sqlToolService.executeSqlWithFiles(sql, source, "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    } else {
        //Only execute SQL
        sqlToolResponse = this.sqlToolService.executeSql(sql, source, "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    }
    Resource file = new UrlResource(("MYPATH/"+sqlToolReponse.getZipName()).toUri());
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + sqlToolResponse.getZipName()) + "\"")
        .body(file);
    }
```

SqlToolResponse :

```
public class SqlToolResponse {

    private String result;
    private String zipName;

    public SqlToolResponse(String someResult, String zip) {
        this.result = someResult;
        this.zipName = zip;
    }

    public SqlToolResponse(String someResult) {
        this.result = someResult;
        this.zipName = null;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public String getZipName() {
        return zipName;
    }

}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method as

```
MultiValueMap<String, Object> handleSqlRequest(@RequestParam("sql") String sql, 
            @RequestParam("source") String source, @RequestParam("genFile") Boolean genFile) {

    // ......
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
    HttpHeaders headers1 = new HttpHeaders();
    headers1.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" 
                           + sqlToolResponse.getZipName()) + "\"");
    HttpEntity<Resource> part1 = new HttpEntity<>(file, headers1);

    HttpHeaders headers2 = new HttpHeaders();
    headers2.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    HttpEntity<String> part2 = new HttpEntity<>(sqlToolReponse.getResult(), headers2);
    body.add("file", part1);
    body.add("string", part2);
    return body;
}
```

Comment: Trying, in your code you're using Spring HttpEntity and MultiValueMap or Apache one ?

Comment: Spring's one org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap and org.springframework.http.HttpEntity

Comment: But how should I interprete the MultiValueMap on the angular side, like that : `this.http.get<MultiValueMap>(/sql).subscribe(data => {
      //some code`  and I got a type error when I try to reproduce your code at `body.put("file",part1);` String, list<object> and String,HttpEntity<string> not applicable

Comment: The method put(String, List<Object>) in the type Map<String,List<Object>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, HttpEntity<Resource>)

Comment: use `add` instead of `put`, updated the answer. At angular side you need to look how to parse formdata response.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple ways to do that:

- return an object having 2 fields (`String` and `File`)
- return a `Map<String, Object>`
- set the string value in a header

Comment: Ok but if I return an object having 2 fields, it forces me to get back the file with an other HTTP get request from the front page using the file.name property in the File object right ?

Comment: Yes.
You also can add the String in a header (in this case you don't have to do another http request)